# how can we create pipelines for modules in a maven project in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have created a job of maven project that which consists of few another maven projects. Now, here I will call this internal maven projects as modules. Now I want to trigger the jobs among the modules. Can I use pipelines for this?
How can I do that? please help me.

[image: This is how modules are there in my project]

Comment: what do you mean by  relationship(pipeline) between modules ? what is your expectation

Answer (score 0):

For basic job chaining, you can use `Post Build action` > "`Build another project`". If you need to pass parameters to the downstream job, you can use `Post Build action` > "`Trigger Parameterized build`".

Comment: Pom12, but in the module configuration there is is no such Post Build Action option, Post Build Action is there for the whole project configuration

Comment: Okay I'm not sure I understand what you call modules... your initial post is very unclear, could you please add more details on your use case, examples, captures, etc ?

Comment: Pom12, I hope my question is clear now. I paraphrased the question.

Comment: Not really, the vocabulary you are using is very unclear. Please read some [Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io) to better describe your problem. There is no such thing as a **module** concept in Jenkins, but instead there are jobs, that can be of different types (freestyle job, maven job, pipeline job) and multiple jobs can be chained together.

Comment: Pom12, please find the image